# Hyper-V Share Host Internet Connection with guests

Tags: hyper-v

I have read a few questions and answers on this subject, but none seemed to relate to my setup. I would like to know if it is possible for my Hyper-V guest VMs to have internet connectivity in the following scenario without having to use public IP addresses for them.

I have Hyper-V running on Win 2012R2, it has a public IP address which is configured on the vEthernet connection and the host has internet connectivity, no problem there.

I would like the Hyper-V guest VMs to have internet connectivity without having to assign them all separate public IP addresses and instead, share the hosts internet connection (in a similar way that VirtualBox allows). I only have 1 public IP address, getting additional (public) IP addresses is not currently possible and there is no (physical) switch that will provide any internal IP addresses.

I do not need to externally access the guest VMs, just require them to have internet connectivity.

My first question is, is this possible? I guess the second question is, how can I achieve this?

I have looked at some similar questions that suggest setting up Virtual Switches, sharing the internet connection, etc... Which I have tried, but have not been able to get this working.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `New-NetNat` powershell command to create a NAT connection for the VMs to connect to the Internet using the host IP address. That's how I achieved this in the past without having to assign external IP addresses (in the same network of the host) to the VMs. [Check this technet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn283361(v=wps.630).aspx)
One question: You say that your Windows Server has a public IP address, are you really using one?

Comment: Hi Humberto, many thanks for your reply. I've taken a quick look at that, I'm not great with PowerShell so will try and understand it. Yes, The Windows (Host) Server has a public IP address configured. Thanks.

Comment: If powershell is kind of new/difficult to you I found [this post](https://blog.areflyen.no/2012/10/10/setting-up-internet-access-for-hyper-v-with-nat-in-windows-8/) that could be useful. I haven't tried before but you can give it a try and see if it works. It states it's for Windows 8 but should work for Server 2012 as you might guess. Come back and post any updates!

Comment: Thanks Humberto, that guide worked perfectly for me, much appreciated.